# Qual a diferença entre método e instrução?

Tags: python

estou estudando python, e eu vi uma coisa que estou em dúvida, quando acrescento algo em uma lista, uso .(ponto), mas quando deleto não, diz ser um método, quando uso o .(ponto), exemplo: `amigos.insert(0, 'colegas de classe')`, e quando não se usa o ponto? Tem algum nome diferente, ou continua sendo um método, só que sem nome?

Comment: Você está citando por exemplo o método `l.append(123)` e a palavra chave `del l[0]`  ?

Comment: é, me refiro a isso.

Comment: A [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del-stmt) chama `del` de "instrução" (em inglês, *statement*). O resto pode ser método ou função, cuja diferença já é explicada nas perguntas indicadas acima no box azul